# Run UFT script from Local Machine on Remote Machine

Tags: automation, remote-access, qtp, hp-uft

I am a newbie in UFT automation, and I am facing this scenario.

**Scenario**: I am accessing an application on a remote machine. And I am trying to automate this application. I have HP UFT installed on my local machine, not on the remote machine.

I want to know if it is possible to automate on the remote machine from my local machine? Could you please point me to some reliable articles so I can it up from there?

I have read articles about setting up DCOM settings and access rights along with some registry settings, but with all suggesting to have UFT installed on the remote machine.

**Note**: I cannot get UFT installed on the remote machine, as it is a third-party machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try insight recording to run it on remote machine

Answer (score 0):

Yes That is right.
You can't Execute your QTP script on Remote Computer if QTP is not installed in Remote Machine.

Cause When you will try to execute the Following line,

```
Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application", "RemoteComputerName")
```

It won't happen. As To run QTP script you need to have QTP where your AUT is present.
If it's not QTPscript (Like Normal VbScript etc) then it's possible using WshController object. 
But that's not your requirement though.

:)